# Cross button in UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar

Greetings
Anybody knows how to show cross button (as bookmark button inside UISearchBar) and implements its functionality?

Thanks in anticipation
MANN

Comment: We need more information. Language, framework, application...

Answer (score 0):

if you use interface builder it is ery easy to show.it is there by default.i have used search bar in my app and the searchbartextfield has an "X" to clear the textfield

Answer (score 0):

@Mann: hey hi wass up

Coming to your query see whenever you type anything into the search bar the X appears automatically and if you touch that X the data from the search field is cleared and you need not to do any extra coding for that, Now coming to the extra part i do apologize i did not understand the next half of the question like

> show cross button (as bookmark button inside UISearchBar)

It would be nice of you to please elaborate the question a bit.